# Error when deploying bna file to Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I'm able to generate my archive file (.bna), but when I run the command to deploy it I get the following error:

```
$ composer network deploy --archiveFile test@1.0.0.bna --enrollId user_type4_1 --enrollSecret <secret> -p bluemix
Deploying business network from archive: test@1.0.0.bna
Business network definition:
Identifier: test@1.0.0
Description:

TypeError: First argument must be a string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or array-like object.
Command failed
```

The `connection.json` file for my `bluemix` profile is:

```
{
  "type": "hlf",
  "membershipServicesURL": "grpcs://6175a0e332ef47a3b87dc1056697e76b-ca.us.blockchain.ibm.com:30001",
  "peerURL": "grpcs://6175a0e332ef47a3b87dc1056697e76b-vp3.us.blockchain.ibm.com:30001",
  "eventHubURL": "grpcs://6175a0e332ef47a3b87dc1056697e76b-vp3.us.blockchain.ibm.com:31001",
  "keyValStore": "/home/jeff/.composer-credentials",
  "deployWaitTime": "300",
  "invokeWaitTime": "100"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Please see
>   [Fabric composer integration with Bluemix blockchain service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42309207/fabric-composer-integration-with-bluemix-blockchain-service), 
>   your connection profile is missing the certificate and certificatePath
>   definition that is required to use secure grpc communications defined
>   in your connection profile. The service provider (bluemix) should have
>   provided the certificate information as part of the connection
>   details.

https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/794