# deploy BNA file on ibm bluemix blockchain service

Tags: ibm-cloud, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am trying to deploy a BNA file on the IBM bluemix blockchain service. I have obtained the BNA file from the composer playground and i could not find a way to push that file on bluemix blockchain service. 
I have tried this [tutorial](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/blockchain/ibmblockchain_tutorials.html)  but they are trying to make a chaincode and then deploying it on the blockchain service of bluemix. 
Why do i have to create a chaincode  for deploying? can't i just push the models and javascript transaction processor functions and then use it via a REST API from the bluemix blockchain service.
 A step by step process for deploying the BNA file(obtained from composer playground) on the bluemix blockchain service would be much appreciated.
 Regards

Comment: I am facing the same issue here. IBM lacks in documentation and they don't give us a step by step on how to deploy a simple application on their service since the creation of a .bna file, generating a card, etc. We need to do a cherry pick on a thousands of tutorials to try to figure out how to deploy it properly. I also opened an issue here, if you want to get updates, here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54661203/ibm-blockchain-simple-application

Answer (score 1):

The link you provide is for Go Lang chaincode, not a Composer Business Network (BNA).  I would suggest the following link, [Fabric composer integration with Bluemix blockchain service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42309207/fabric-composer-integration-with-bluemix-blockchain-service).

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to deploy a chaincode, to IBM-Blockchain, not a .bna file. To link your .bna file with the deployed code, you'd need to download the connections settings of your blockchain (which can be found at Overview/Connection Profile) and put it at the same directory of your .bna file.

The image below says where you can find the connections settings:

[image: Connection Profile]