# Build failing while deploying Perishable network on IBM cloud Blockchain starter plan

Tags: build, ibm-blockchain

- nvm_tree_contains_path /home/pipeline/.nvm /home/pipeline/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.1
- '[' -n 'Now using node v8.15.1 (npm v6.4.1)' ']'
- nvm_echo 'Now using node v8.15.1 (npm v6.4.1)'
- command printf '%s\n' 'Now using node v8.15.1 (npm v6.4.1)'
- node -v
  Now using node v8.15.1 (npm v6.4.1)
- npm -v
  v8.15.1
  6.4.1
- test_contracts
- for CONTRACT in '${CONTRACTS}'
- test_contract iot-blockchain-perishable-network
- CONTRACT=iot-blockchain-perishable-network
- '[' -f contracts/iot-blockchain-perishable-network/package.json ']'
- test_composer_contract iot-blockchain-perishable-network
- CONTRACT=iot-blockchain-perishable-network
- echo testing composer contract iot-blockchain-perishable-network
- pushd contracts/iot-blockchain-perishable-network
- npm test
  testing composer contract iot-blockchain-perishable-network
  ~/bc70ab6b-afeb-4ddf-a8ee-ddb7b7e23ce1/contracts/iot-blockchain-perishable-network ~/bc70ab6b-afeb-4ddf-a8ee-ddb7b7e23ce1

> perishable-network@0.2.6-deploy.2 pretest /home/pipeline/bc70ab6b-afeb-4ddf-a8ee-ddb7b7e23ce1/contracts/iot-blockchain-perishable-network
>   npm run lint
>
> perishable-network@0.2.6-deploy.2 lint /home/pipeline/bc70ab6b-afeb-4ddf-a8ee-ddb7b7e23ce1/contracts/iot-blockchain-perishable-network
>   eslint .

sh: 1: eslint: not found
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! perishable-network@0.2.6-deploy.2 lint: `eslint .`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the perishable-network@0.2.6-deploy.2 lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/pipeline/.npm/_logs/2019-03-06T14_37_44_449Z-debug.log
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.

Finished: FAILED

Answer (score 0):

You will just need to run `npm install` and see if everything was successfully installed. Because the project will run inside IBM Blockchain, you dont need to run it locally.

For a more detailed information on how to achieve your gold, check this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55358606/7004017