# How do we fix this IBM Platform blockchain error?

Tags: blockchain, ibm-blockchain

Issue creating smart contract project:

```
Could not parse JSON in file: C:\Users\xxxxx\package.json. Detail: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 78
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably running it under the wrong composer version. You need to restart from the beginning using those versions:

```
composer-rest-server -v
v0.20.5

composer -v
v0.20.5
```

For a more detailed information on how to achieve your goal, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55358606/7004017